# Show Aggregate from another ClientDataSet

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, delphi-10-seattle

I work on a project contain 2 `ClientDataSet` the first `ClientDataSet1` contain a field with type `DataSet` set to `ClientDataSet2`
I want show sum of field (Value) in `ClientDataSet2` in field (Sum) in `ClientDataSet1`
Now I use aggregate to get the sum but I can't show it in `ClientDataSet1`
I had search and read for 2 days but I can't get it to work
[image: This is a simple application show what I need]

Comment: If I understood it correctly you are trying to use `nested datasets` to achieve what you want. AFAIK you can't do that directly. Anyway, check [Cary Jensen's article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29825). You might find its information useful.

Comment: @GuillemVicens Yes its nested, it looks great article, this will help me understand many things, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it

```
procedure TForm1.ClientDataSet2AfterPost(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  if ClientDataSet2Sum.Value <> null then
  ClientDataSet1Sum.Value := ClientDataSet2Sum.Value;
end;
```